# Visual Studio 2012 editor line of dashes not displayed correctly

Tags: editor, visual-studio-2012

Try entering following line of dashes in Visual Studio 2012 editor:

//--------------------------------------------

After 90 dashes it seems that the editor inserts 2 spaces. But it's not! If you copy and paste the line to notepad it reveals that the line of dashes are intact.

Feature or Bug ?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a bug, I've seen this as well and thought there is something wrong with my installation. They've released a feedback tool which can be used for bug submission. Try it: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8a5aac8-0418-4f88-9d34-bdbe2c4cfe72